# How do I configure vim to show a character when a line is too long to be displayed?

Tags: vimrc, line-breaks

I want to be notified when a line is too long to fit in the window.

Right now I have this in `~/.vimrc`:

```
set wrap
let &showbreak = '        +++ '
```

I'd like to change that to:

```
set nowrap
let &somesetting = ' > '
```

Such that `somesetting` tells vim to put a `>` on the right margin of any line is too long to be fully displayed.

I coulda sworn vim could do this but I can't find the setting.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should the this

```
:set listchars+=precedes:<,extends:>
```

Ref:

- `:h wrap`
- `:h 'listchars'`